# The set of continuously differentiable functions such that $f(0)=0$, $f(1)=1$, $|f'|\le 3/4$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

I came across the following problem:

Let $C^{1}(\mathbb{R})$ be the collection of continuously differentiable functions on $\mathbb{R}$.Let 
$S$=$\{f \in C^{1}(\mathbb{R}):f(0)=0,f(1)=1,|f'(x)|\leqslant 3/4, \forall x\in \mathbb{R} \}.$Then which of the following option is correct?

> (a) S is empty,
>   (b) S is non-empty and finite,
>   (c) S is countably infinite,
>   (d) S is uncountable.

I do not know how to progress. Please help.Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: I suggest that you think about how the Mean Value Theorem or the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus can be applied.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the mean value theorem there must be a point $x\in(0,1)$ where 
$$
    f'(x) = \frac{f(1) - f(0)}{1-0} = 1
$$
That should answer your question.

Comment: Thanks a lot.I have got it. Since in $S$,$|f'(x)|\leqslant 3/4$ whereas $|f'(x)|=1$,$S$ must be empty.So $(a)$ will be the correct choice.